# Linux - Escape double quotes

Tags: shell

I have wrapper script that remotes into another server via ssh and runs another shell script with supplied arguments as input parameter

```
sshwrapper.sh "executequery.ksh SYNC N \\\"\\\" \\\"\\\" \"\\\"dt='2017-02-10'\\\"\""
```

When I execute the above, the executequery.ksh receives the arguments as below on the remote server (working as expected)

```
SYNC "" "" "dt='2017-02-10'"
```

However, when I run through the Informatica it implicitily runs as below.

```
sh -c "command"
```

Now, in the command it substitutes the above, it fails.  That is

```
sh -c "sshwrapper.sh "executequery.ksh SYNC N \\\"\\\" \\\"\\\" \"\\\"dt='2017-02-10'\\\"\"""
```

Can you please help to escape the double quotes, but should still manage to supply the input arguments as

```
SYNC "" "" "dt='2017-02-10'"
```

Comment: If you need more than three backslashes in a row, you're probably doing it wrong.  I'd suggest you need to write a script, copy the script to the remote machine, and then execute the script.

Comment: sorry, not sure I understand your point of correction.  The command runs fine with no issues when you invoke manually.  It is only when invoking through Informatica it fails, because Informatica reconstructs the statement implicitly as sh -c "command".  I just need to be able to escape the double quotes

Comment: It is correct to escape quotes only once, when needed. So, `"executequery.ksh SYNC N \"\" ..."` would be correct. Note the single escapes. Then, `executequery.ksh` must treat correctly its parameters, **even if they contain spaces or quotes**.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping your working command within a layer of quotes... problem is that your quotes are no longer matching... why do you have to put command in double inverted commas? It would help me to understand where within informatica this runs and how you've set command i.e. if command is a variable I'd expect it to be $$command and then I'd ask what happens when you run sh -c $$command?

Also try

sshwrapper.sh executequery.ksh SYNC N "" "" ""dt='2017-02-10'""